# Regular expression remove tag after a paragraph with a given class

Tags: css, regex, bbedit

Is there a way to select all `<br>` tags that follow a paragraph with a given class? i.e. `<p class="myclass">This is a paragraph</p><br>`

There may be other `<br>` in the HTML so I cannot use this:

```
br {display:none;}
```

and I cannot delete all `<br>` tags. If there is a way to select these particular `<br>` tags then I can use CSS.

There are about 700 pages and I do not want to go through each of them to make sure if the `<br>` is needed or not.  I do know that it is not needed following a paragraph with the class of "myclass".

If there is no way to select these tags then I think that I can use BBEdit to do the search and replace using a regular expression. But I don't know how to write the RE that would work.

TIA,
Linda

Comment: sorry, what has this got to do with regexes? and what is stopping you from using `br.myclass {display:none;}`

Comment: @tobyodavies did you even read the whole question? The regex would be used as a filter to find all the br elements that need to be deleted in the web site code. Additionally, br.myclass would not work as a selector given the example @Linda provided.

Comment: The question said 'select all br tags with a given class', and the example didn't make a lot of sense to me... tho your answer clears it up... and i _still_ don't see what its got to do with regexes

Comment: Couldn't you just use the normal find and replace dialogue to find `</p><br>` and replace with `</p>`? EDIT: see my answer - it's not programming, but since you stipulated you're using BBEdit it should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p.myClass+br {display:none;}
```

This will select all `<br>` elements that are **directly adjacent** to a `<p class="myClass">` element.  If you need anything more dynamic than that, you *will* need regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BBEdit is similar to TextWrangler, you could use the built in Find dialogue.

Go to Search > Find... (Command + F), do "Seach For" `</p><br>` and "Replace With" `</p>` and then use the "Multi-file search" option at the bottom of the window to choose your files.

This isn't a regex, but since you said you're using BBEdit, which is made by Bare Bones and supposedly shares a lot with TextWrangler, it should work. (Otherwise just download TW for free). It even gives you a nice pop-up telling you what it found and replaced in case you want to review, etc.

See [this page](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html) for more info on BBEdit's search and other fun features.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to use regex to delete all `<br>` tags that follow a paragraph with a class named `myclass`:

Search for: `(<p\b[^><]\sclass\s=\s*["']?myclass["']?[^><]>.?<\/p>\s*)<br\s*/?>`

Replace with: `$1`

Note, you must ensure that all `p` tags in your HTML documents are properly closed.